# what kind of memory assigned to array object of size zero?

Tags: java, arrays, string

As for my understanding object is very much synonym for memory assign for any entity.

```
String array[]=new String[0];
```

since size of array is zero and which can't be increase in case of array,so what kind of memory assigned to this zero sized array object?

Comment: I used to go through this question before asking .no man this is quit different from what i am asking

Comment: The same as an array of one element, minus the element.

Comment: then what rest there in object.is this will be empty or it would retain some other info like gc,hashcode,size etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Memory would still be assigned, although there would be no values within the array, just the array header. The header would consist of things like specific flags, the length of the array and also the type of the array (here it is `Object`). The compiler won't just ignore this array, even though it's length is zero, because it may still be referenced and could be resized with `System.arraycopy()` etc.

The advantage of creating the array rather than setting it to null, is that it can be safely traversed through a for loop without throwing a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: `System.arraycopy` doesn't resize an array.

Answer (score 4):

It is often used to signal that there are no elements in the array. This can be considered more "friendly" than representing "no data" by `null`, allowing for iteration without throwing an exception:

```
for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
    // Do stuff, will not throw NullPointerException
}
```

This also allows for the conversion to `List` if the need were to arise.

Answer (score 1):

A single-dimension array is a single object. As expected, the array has the usual object header. However, this object head is 12 bytes to accommodate a four-byte array length.

Reference:
http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/memory/array_memory_usage.shtml

Hope that answers your question.